# unable to insert images and use wysiwyg properly

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, wysiwyg, media-images

i am working on magento website which is based on magento 1.9.
all of sudden am facing a wierd issue that wysiwyg editor is not working properly as when am trying to insert any image same is not getting inserted and even unable to use editor for other purposes too
request if anyone can please help in this.

url : https://i-ranu.com

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error message?

Comment: the issue was with hosting provider and same is sorted now. ( thanks )